# How to use nested IF and AND multiple conditioning

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want use nested IF with AND expression. But getting error. It is possible?

My example code: testing two values, if true return range,if not true test second two conditions if true return another range and so on...

```
=if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=0.8),{cennik!A4:G17},if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=1),{cennik!A26:G39))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your formula near the end - there is a missing `}`:

```
=if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=0.8),{cennik!A4:G17},if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=1),{cennik!A26:G39}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets formulas use semicolons as separators instead of commas.

Try this one:

```
=if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=0.8);{cennik!A4:G17};if(AND(Vstup!B16=150,Vstup!B17=1);{cennik!A26:G39))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(AND(Vstup!B16=150; Vstup!B17=0.8); cennik!A4:G17;
       IF(AND(Vstup!B16=150, Vstup!B17=1);   cennik!A26:G39; )))
```